# Refresh query table when cell changes

Tags: excel, vba, refresh, powerquery, onchange

I've build a number of tables using Power Query.  For table "TemplateDataQry", I have a parameter value in cell "G2".  The table resides on sheet "TemplateData"

What code is needed to automatically refresh the query when the the parameter cell changes?  i have not located anything yet that would work.

Comment: Perhaps using the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event?

Comment: While it's feasible I don't think it's practical, refreshing takes so much time and some other things may trigger easily this, why don't you set a shape within the sheet to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I found using the Worksheet Event pointing at the the parameter cell was the easiest way to handle it.